# How do I configure the small icon that appears when my app part is inserted?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I've been able to configure the app icon for my app part, which appears in the app catalog in SharePoint. However, when my app is inserted onto a page a grey cube is rendered, rather than the icon. Does anyone know how to configure this in my app setup?

[image: insert app parts]

Comment: Did you find  a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, we did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the elements.xml file of the App-Part you add a property CatalogIconImageUrl with the path to the image. Note that the image has to be 16x16 pixels in size

```
<properties>
   <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string">path/to/image.png</property>
</properties>
```

Comment: This creates an error when trying to deploy the app: ClientWebPart has the Property CatalogIconImageUrl which cannot be used since its declared on a base class

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the icon file name is hardcoded to "SPStoreFrontAppDefault.16x16x32.png" and cannot be changed for app parts:

[image]

Terrible!