# Can I change the Icon for my App Part?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm playing around with SharePoint apps, and have my app working. However, I'm trying to brand it at the moment.I have been able to change the Icon that you see on the Site Contents page. What I want to do now, is changed the little icon next to the ClientAppPart when I click insert App.

How do I do this? I know how to do this with WebParts, by adding the property CatalogIconImageUrl.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Did you find the solution?

Comment: I never found the answer to the solution. I don't believe it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the icon file name is hardcoded to "SPStoreFrontAppDefault.16x16x32.png" and cannot be changed for app parts:

[image]

Terrible!

(Same question and answer here: [How do I configure the small icon that appears when my app part is inserted?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151143/how-do-i-configure-the-small-icon-that-appears-when-my-app-part-is-inserted))